# Get fish shell to work with gcloud command line tools?

Tags: fish, gcloud

Has anyone had any luck getting fish shell to work with google's gcloud command line tools? I'm not an expert in Fish script but these are the two files gcloud needs to run (which work fine use Fish's bash mode). Fish doesn't allow you to source bash files from what I understand so these would need to be converted to Fish script?

path.bash

```
script_link="$( readlink "$BASH_SOURCE" )" || script_link="$BASH_SOURCE"
apparent_sdk_dir="${script_link%/*}"
if [ "$apparent_sdk_dir" == "$script_link" ]; then
  apparent_sdk_dir=.
fi
sdk_dir="$( command cd -P "$apparent_sdk_dir" && pwd -P )"
bin_path="$sdk_dir/bin"
export PATH=$bin_path:$PATH
```

path.completion

```
_python_argcomplete() {
    local IFS=''
    COMPREPLY=( $(IFS="$IFS"                   COMP_LINE="$COMP_LINE"                   COMP_POINT="$COMP_POINT"                   _ARGCOMPLETE_COMP_WORDBREAKS="$COMP_WORDBREAKS"                   _ARGCOMPLETE=1                   "$1" 8>&1 9>&2 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null) )
    if [[ $? != 0 ]]; then
        unset COMPREPLY
    fi
}
complete -o default -F _python_argcomplete "gcloud"

_completer() {
    command=$1
    name=$2
    eval '[[ "$'"${name}"'_COMMANDS" ]] || '"${name}"'_COMMANDS="$('"${command}"')"'
    set -- $COMP_LINE
    shift
    while [[ $1 == -* ]]; do
          shift
    done
    [[ $2 ]] && return
    grep -q "${name}\s*$" <<< $COMP_LINE &&
        eval 'COMPREPLY=($'"${name}"'_COMMANDS)' &&
        return
    [[ "$COMP_LINE" == *" " ]] && return
    [[ $1 ]] &&
        eval 'COMPREPLY=($(echo "$'"${name}"'_COMMANDS" | grep ^'"$1"'))'
}

unset bq_COMMANDS
_bq_completer() {
    _completer "CLOUDSDK_COMPONENT_MANAGER_DISABLE_UPDATE_CHECK=1 bq help | grep '^[^ ][^ ]*  ' | sed 's/ .*//'" bq
}

unset gsutil_COMMANDS
_gsutil_completer() {
    _completer "CLOUDSDK_COMPONENT_MANAGER_DISABLE_UPDATE_CHECK=1 gsutil help | sed /Additional/q | grep '^  ' | sed -e 's/^  //' -e 's/ .*//'" gsutil
}

unset gcutil_COMMANDS
_gcutil_completer() {
    _completer "CLOUDSDK_COMPONENT_MANAGER_DISABLE_UPDATE_CHECK=1 gcutil help | grep -v '^information' | grep '^[a-z]' | sed -e 's/ .*//' -e '/^$/d'" gcutil
}

complete -o default -F _bq_completer bq
complete -o default -F _gsutil_completer gsutil
complete -o default -F _gcutil_completer gcutil
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

What worked for me was just using bass. Check it out:
https://github.com/edc/bass

Just take the lines that gcloud adds to your bash_profile, and prepend bass to them in your `.config/fish/config.fish` file, as follows:

```
# The next line updates PATH for the Google Cloud SDK.
bass source '/Users/hunter/bin/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc'

# The next line enables shell command completion for gcloud.
bass source '/Users/hunter/bin/google-cloud-sdk/completion.bash.inc'
```

Comment: Thank you 100 times... Bass is awesome!

Comment: This doesn't appear to work anymore, or rather, I get files and folders for autocomplete when I hit tab.

Comment: https://github.com/Doctusoft/google-cloud-sdk-fish-completion doing that combined with 
`source '...../google-cloud-sdk/path.fish.inc'`
worked for me.

Comment: I installed that repo and thought it was it, but in the end, I added `bass source ~/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc` to `~/.config/fish/config.fish` to make it work for new terminals

Comment: "bass!" in my language means "enough!". This was enough. +1 :)

Answer (score 17):

As of today, I was able just to do

1. `brew install --cask google-cloud-sdk`
2. Added `source /usr/local/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/path.fish.inc` to my `~/.config/fish/config.fish`
3. Clone https://github.com/aliz-ai/google-cloud-sdk-fish-completion then run `install.sh`.

Comment: This is the working solution for me. To install it with oh-my-fish:

`$ omf install git@github.com:aliz-ai/google-cloud-sdk-fish-completion.git`

Comment: For me above command gave permission error. ```$ omf install https://github.com/lgathy/google-cloud-sdk-fish-completion.git``` . this worked

Comment: Step 3 was enough for me. Thanks!

Comment: For homebrew 3.4.11: `source /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/path.fish.inc`

Answer (score 5):

For path.bash, all it does is add the Cloud SDK bin directory to your PATH. We put some weird stuff in there because we wanted it to work from inside the Cloud SDK directory even when behind, eg, a symlink. For your own system, just do the fsh equivalent of "export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/google-cloud-sdk/bin".

For the tab completion, I don't know how fsh's tab completion works, so I've got nothing.

Comment: And what is the fsh equivalent of "export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/google-cloud-sdk/bin"?

Comment: Using the `fish_user_paths` universal variable is one of the possibilities: `set -U fish_user_paths $fish_user_paths /path/to/google-cloud-sdk/bin`.

Comment: In what way @GeorgeKatsanos? I've just tried it (again) and it works for me.

Comment: add to path in fish: `set -gx $PATH /path/to/google-cloud-sdk/bin`

Answer (score 3):

I was able to set up completion by executing this:

```
# fisher v3
fisher add lgathy/google-cloud-sdk-fish-completion

# fisher v4
fisher install lgathy/google-cloud-sdk-fish-completion
```

Fisher can be found here: https://github.com/jorgebucaran/fisher

Completion source: https://github.com/lgathy/google-cloud-sdk-fish-completion

Comment: Works out of the box! Thank you!

Comment: Works out of the box for arguments/sub-commands but not options e.g. `--filter`.

Comment: Looks like aliz-ai/google-cloud-sdk-fish-completion redirects now to https://github.com/lgathy/google-cloud-sdk-fish-completion. Updating answer.

Answer (score 2):

Fish support is now included out of the box with gcloud, however I ran into a pretty annoying issue. The code included in `google-cloud-sdk/path.fish.inc` (and @nafg's answer) leaves the directory changed, resulting in each new shell session starting in the `google-cloud-sdk` directory.

The modification I made was fairly simple, adding two extra lines to get the current working directory and restore it afterwards. This seems to have resolved the issue for me, so hopefully will help anyone else googling for "fish gcloud" problems.

```
set restore_dir (pwd -P)
set sdk_dir (builtin cd "$apparent_sdk_dir" > /dev/null; and pwd -P)
set bin_path "$sdk_dir/bin"
cd "$restore_dir"
```

Comment: what do you mean "out of the box" ? I just installed it and it doesn't work.

Comment: It seems like this is fixed now.

Comment: how did u install gcloud? brew? apt? I think that this file doesnt exist in all packages

Comment: It doesn't seem to come out of the box with homebrew on mac.

Comment: This lists completions for zsh but not fish. https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/blob/ea70f7a70ccafb51dd060ab565e3ec8f9a62e60a/Casks/g/google-cloud-sdk.rb#L66-L76

Answer (score 1):

There's an interesting approach here: http://michelpm.com/blog/2013/07/26/switching-from-zsh-to-fish/

Basically it will run a bash script in bash, but it will diff how it changes the environment and apply that in fish.

However it won't work for completions and for your path.bash it's overkill. More like:

- Change var=value to set var value
- Change [ ... ] to test ...
- Change $( ... ) to ( ... )
- `if` doesn't need `then` and ends with `end`
- Change `||` to `; or` and `&&` to `; and`
- Change export to set -x

So without testing here's what I would try:

```
set script_link ( readlink "$BASH_SOURCE" ); or set script_link $BASH_SOURCE
set apparent_sdk_dir ${script_link%/*}
if test "$apparent_sdk_dir" == "$script_link" ;
  set apparent_sdk_dir .
end
set sdk_dir ( command cd -P "$apparent_sdk_dir"; and pwd -P )
set bin_path $sdk_dir/bin
set -x PATH $bin_path:$PATH
```

Comment: For path.bash I would edit your PATH the normal way, by adding the directory to the path directly. We added path.bash to make it easy for people who weren't familiar with dot-files, but a fsh user most likely is.

Answer (score 1):

using fisher:

```
fisher install lgathy/google-cloud-sdk-fish-completion
```

and you are good to go

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to include an explanation of how this works and why it is the solution to the problem described in the question. See [answer].